# Fisher Information and vector differentiation

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus

I have $\theta = [a,b]^T$ and the loglikelihood function $l(z|\theta)$

The score $V=\frac{\partial l(z|\theta)}{\partial \vec\theta}$

Then the fisher information matrix $Fi$ is the variance of the score. (Definition)

Now there are some things I don't understand (and my problems are probably more fundamental than only fisher information)

First of all

Why is $Fi = E[V^TV]$ and not just $Fi = E[V^2]$ or $Fi = Var[V]$

Secondly,
As far as I know

$V=\frac{\partial l(z|\theta)}{\partial \vec\theta} = (\frac{\partial l(z|\theta)}{\partial a} , \frac{\partial l(z|\theta)}{\partial b})^T$

So when I follow the definition of Fisher matrix
$Fi = E[V^TV] = E[\begin{bmatrix}
  (\frac{\partial l(z|\theta)}{\partial a})^2 & \frac{(\partial l(z|\theta))^2}{\partial a \partial b} \\
  \frac{(\partial l(z|\theta))^2}{\partial a \partial b}  & (\frac{\partial l(z|\theta)}{\partial b})^2
 \end{bmatrix}]$

Which is wrong because my course notes have the hessian so I should have second derivatives. What did I do wrong when working out $V^TV$ ?

Answer (score 2):

1. In multi-parameter case, derivative of the score is a vector rather than scalar. So the definition of FIM measures the covariance, not variance, of $V$, which induces $\mathbb E[VV^T]$ appear.
2. You can verify that the identity
   $$\mathcal I_{ij}=\mathbb E[\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta_i}\frac{\partial l}{\partial \theta_j}]=-\mathbb E[\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j}]$$
   in which view you can see easily that FIM is related to Hessian of score. And the indentity can be shown from direct calculation by expanding $l$.

Comment: Thanks already. I still seem to have some difficulties proving the identity. Could you maybe give me a hint?

Comment: What's your first though? I think it a not difficult computation.